# Exclude CREATE,ALTER, DROP table using SED command in LINUX for Audit Log

Tags: unix, sed

I already made daily audit log for sybase database's but I need to exclude all of CREATE ALTER DROP table result from this log using "sed" command.

I made a extention .sh dbtran -g command to make daily log audit

can someone help me?

```
date >> /root/startdbtran.txt
dbtran -g /data/testpotongdr/backup/backup/multimipspnew.log /data/testpotongdr/backup/dbtran/multimipspnew_`date --date='yesterday' '+%Y%m%d'`_tranlog.sql -j `date --date='yesterday' '+%Y%m%d'`
date >> /root/enddbtran.txt

sed -e '/dbping/d;/Trigger\|Attempting operation/s/--AUDIT/--TRIGAUDIT/g' /data/testpotongdr/backup/dbtran/multimipspnew_`date --date='yesterday' '+%Y%m%d'`_tranlog.sql |
    sed -e '/--AUDIT/s/$/\nbeende_von_einem_netzwerk/g'|
    sed -e '/Attempting operation\|BEGIN TRIGGER\|--AUDIT/,/Operation Succeeded\|\
        Operation Failed\|END TRIGGER\|beende_von_einem_netzwerk\|^--COMMIT WORK/!d
        s/TRIGAUDIT/AUDIT/g
        /beende_von_einem_netzwerk/d' -e 's/^/--XAUDIT/g;s/--XAUDIT\(-*AUDIT\)/\1/g'| logger -i=
```

Result of this syntax is just a log from one day transaction with extention xxxxxx.log

At syntax, it makes log including audit option. That means ALL operation included like CREATE, ALTER, DROP table and UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE record. So, what's the syntax for exclude CREATE, ALTER, DROP table and UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE record using SED?

Comment: Better put sample input and expected output please

Comment: Oke,,here's the syntax

Comment: can you provide a sample content of the log file?

Comment: if the records for CREATE, ALTER and DROP are present in a single line, you can use the sed 'd' command to delete those lines

Comment: Why pipe multiple `sed` together when all could be done with one `sed` instance and multiple `-e` arguments?